# How to set up different colors for UISegmentedControl buttons?

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I have an `UISegmentedControl` with two buttons. I want each button of control to have specific color of borders and title.

Is is possible and if yes how it can be archived?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `segmentedControlStyle` property. Which gives you 3 different styles
`UISegmentedControlStylePlain, UISegmentedControlStyleBordered, UISegmentedControlStyleBar`. If you want any other appearance, you'll need to make a custom control.

Doc: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISegmentedControl/segmentedControlStyle